# Error with loading png in Rmd file

Tags: r, png, r-markdown

i am trying (invane) to load a png file in my Rmd file.
I save both the Rmd and the png in the same folder on my main drive (I tested i can read/write files in there with R).

When i run the following code

````
---
title: "Determinants of profitability"
author: "Daniele Frison"
date: "26 November 2015"
output:
  html_document:
    fig_height: 10
    fig_width: 10
---

```{r}

![aaa](prof_vs_costs.png) 

```
````

I get inexorably this error message:

```
  |................................                                 |  50%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: unnamed-chunk-1


processing file: test.Rmd
Quitting from lines 13-16 (test.Rmd) 
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:2:2: unexpected '['
1: 
2: ![
    ^
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse

Execution halted
```

I can't find what is the problem with this parse.

Thanks in advance for your kind help

Comment: this is markdown and should be _outside_ of r code chunks

Comment: thanks a lot, solved!