# rmarkdown error with ggplot and png

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have tried (in vain) to produce a chart with ggplot in Rmarkdown. 
The code is the following:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE}
#fig.width=12,fig.height=6
panel2$PlotSize<-round(log(panel2$BSFA0200),0)- min(round(log(panel2$BSFA0200),0))+1# set size of dots
panel2$PlotSize[panel2$PlotSize==-Inf]<-NA
panel2$PlotColour<-ifelse(panel2$PlotSize<7,1,panel2$PlotSize)
panel2$PlotSize<-as.factor(panel2$PlotSize)
panel2$PlotColour<-as.factor(panel2$PlotColour)

g1<-ggplot(data=panel2,aes(x=NFR,y=PROF7*100,size=PlotSize,colour=PlotSize))+ geom_point()

g1

```
````

Out of knits this works fine, however when executed within a Rmd file (either as html or pdf) I always get this error message

```
processing file: 1Profti_model.Rmd
  |..                                                               |   4%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.....                                                            |   8%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |........                                                         |  12%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........                                                       |  15%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 3
 $ echo   : logi FALSE
 $ warning: logi FALSE
 $ message: logi FALSE


Attaching package: 'dplyr'

The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: 'zoo'

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

  |............                                                     |  19%
   inline R code fragments

  |...............                                                  |  23%
label: unnamed-chunk-2 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

  |..................                                               |  27%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................                                             |  31%
label: unnamed-chunk-3 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

Quitting from lines 98-109 (1Profti_model.Rmd) 
Error in png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : unable to start png() device
Calls: <Anonymous> ... in_dir -> plot2dev -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> png
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Removed 55 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
  unable to open file '1Profti_model_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-3-1.png' for writing
3: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : opening device failed

Execution halted
```

I also tried to work around the problem by saving the chart in a png and load it as picture afterwards. Also no results (see [Error with loading png in Rmd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136738/error-with-loading-png-in-rmd-file))

Thanks for your help

UPDATE:

Following the suggestions from some of you guys I added a different chunk name and I replicated the code from Davit on my data (see updated code).
Unfortunately the error is still there. Interestingly, knitr cannot write a png but can write a csv in the same folder where the code is (I tested it).

Finally, i tested running this very same code onto my C drive and (surprise!) it works. However, this is for me not very efficient as I don't want to be dependent on a specific machine and I need to share this work with others (so network drive is a must). Moreover, all other package/code work fine in the network drive, only this png() seems to be an issue.

Thanks in advance for you help!
    ---
    title: New Document
    author: Me
    output:
      html_document
    ---

````
```{r prova,echo=FALSE, results='asis', message = FALSE, error = FALSE, warning= FALSE}
#.libPaths("D:/xxxx/packages")
require(ggplot2)

 panel2 <- data.frame(BSFA0200 = rnorm(100),
                        NFR = rnorm(100),
                        PROF7 = rnorm(100))

panel2$PlotSize<-round(log(panel2$BSFA0200),0)- min(round(log(panel2$BSFA0200),0))+1# set size of dots
panel2$PlotSize[panel2$PlotSize==-Inf]<-NA
panel2$PlotColour<-ifelse(panel2$PlotSize<7,2,panel2$PlotSize)

write.csv(panel2[1:100,c('BSFA0200',"NFR","PROF7")],file="test.csv")

g1 <- ggplot(data = panel2,
             aes(x = NFR,
                 y = PROF7 * 100,
                 size = factor(PlotSize),
                 colour = factor(PlotSize)
                 ))

g1 + geom_point()

```
````

Error output:

```
Loading required package: ggplot2

Quitting from lines 9-32 (test.Rmd) 
Error in png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : unable to start png() device
Calls: <Anonymous> ... in_dir -> plot2dev -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> png
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Removed 35 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
  unable to open file 'test_files/figure-html/prova-1.png' for writing
3: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : opening device failed
Execution halted
```

My knitr version is 1.11 (it should be the latest) and R version is 3.2.2

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "i386-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "i386"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "i386, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "2.2"

$year
[1] "2015"

$month
[1] "08"

$day
[1] "14"

$`svn rev`
[1] "69053"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)"

$nickname
[1] "Fire Safety"
```

Comment: in the rmarkdown tab to the right there are two smaller tabs, `Output` and `Issues`. what does it say under issues? what kind of file permissions do you have?

Comment: Is it specifically `ggplot` that is causing the problem? Can you knit a base plot? Do you perhaps not have write access to the folder?

Comment: @rawr The message in the Issue is: Error in png(...,res = dpi, units = "in"): unable to start png() device Calls: <Anonmymous> ...in_dir -> plot2dev -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> png. In addition: Warning messages: 1: In png(...,res = dpi, units = "in"): unable to open file 'XXXX/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-3-1.png'for writing. 2: In png(...,res = dpi, units = "in"): Opening device failed

Comment: @Axeman: Indeed I tested read and write of a csv file in the same folder via knitr and it worked fine. Moreover, the ggplot code works fine out of knitr.

Comment: you're not redefining the default figure location are you?

Comment: I tested both with and without the default figure location but it doesn't seem to mater. knitr::opts_chunk$set(base.dir = 'J:/xxx/code/')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.dir = 'J:/xxxy/charts/')

Comment: @Axeman dear Axeman, you are indeed right, I cannot knit any base plot. I have the same error even with a plainvanilla chart  hist(panel2$NFR,breaks=100) There must be something wrong in the chunk. In case i don't define any default figure location, how should the chunk look like? is there any specific setting? My problem is that not only I can't run a ggplot figure, but also I can't import any picture saved in the drive.

Comment: I'm out of breadth here, sorry.

Comment: I had a similar issue once and it turned out to be because the file I was trying to write to (in your case `unnamed-chunk-3-1.png`) was in use by another process and was locked. Try deleting the file? Try to name your chunk (you add a chunk title like this: `{r chunk_title,echo=FALSE}`) to see if the issue comes from the filename?

Comment: Please add a minimal example that reproduces the error on your system. Also add your R and `knitr` version. This sounds like [this bug](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/942) from `knitr` 1.8.

Comment: Any luck here?  I'm having the same issue when rendering a local file to a network drive.

Answer (score 9):

I got this message as well. The trouble with mine was that the file path was too long. I had my R markdown file in too many sub folders and the name of my R markdown file was too long. Once I reduced the length of the file path, the problem was resolved. I hope that works for you.

Comment: I found this as well when using render. I was writing to a long path over my smb service and it failed on writing the png. When I switched to using a local scratch dir, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue once. The code below works. You either had bad header or didn't call the packages: it's hard to tell since you did not provide that information. Also, please post example data next time.

Here is the full code that works (at least for me). If it doesn't run on your machine, post your data and full Rmd script and I'll try to help.

````
---
title: New Document
author: Me
output:
  html_document
---

```{r,echo=FALSE, results='asis', message = FALSE, error = FALSE, warning= FALSE}
require(ggplot2)

panel2 <- data.frame(BSFA0200 = rnorm(100),
                      NFR = rnorm(100),
                      PROF7 = rnorm(100),
                      PlotSize = factor(rep(1:10, 10)),
                      PlotColour = factor(1:100))

g1 <- ggplot(data = panel2,
             aes(x = NFR,
                 y = PROF7 * 100,
                 size = PlotSize,
                 colour = PlotSize))

g1 + geom_point()
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also received this error; I solved it by moving the code to generate the offending figure into its own chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. And in my case, the issue was that **antivirus** software blocked **`Rscript.exe`** while it was trying to process files while knitting and PNG file was not created. So sometimes it is useful to temporarily disable antivirus and check if this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same error. I understood it was something related to  the path but couldn't solve it. Looking at the comments here, I tried closing the software and reopening it. It worked quickly. If this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

To me this error happened after rendering my page using distil r package and jekyl. I had no chance of detecting the cause. But after reading [this issue here](https://github.com/rstudio/distill/issues/485), I solved it. Apparently, jekyll was the main cause of the page build failure as a result of "`Invalid byte sequencece UTF-8...`". This  was automagically resolved after adding an empty `.nojekyll` file in the root directory of my website. Simply open a text editor and save the emty file as `.nojekyll` and the pushyour chages to github.Good luck.